# What is this long shadow used mostly in icons called?

Tags: style-identification, shadows

In this photo:

[image]

Behind the bird bit there is a 'modern' type of shadow used in advertising.

What is it called?

Comment: Just insert in Google: how to swift logo paint.net - there r tutes for you

Comment: More than a shadow is a (stylized) motion blur imho.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini unless the bird is flying into fire ;)

Comment: @SaturnsEye, yeah, [Mozilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#History) rules ;-) (ok, nowadays it's a [database](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)).

Answer (score 5):

It's a **cast shadow**.

Cast shadows are designed to show a lower level of a pseudo light angle, thus creating longer shadows. Drop shadows are designed to show a high level of pseudo light resulting in a small offset shadow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider this to be a *new kind of shadow*. I think it is still called a "drop shadow".

Also i agree with the comments. Imo this is not a shadow in your picture, it's a motion blur, eventhough it should be white.

Answer (score 1):

Long Shadow. 
Learn how to make them here: http://www.awwwards.com/flat-long-shadows-step-by-step-tutorial-resources-and-examples.html

Comment: oh come on...this answers the question 100%. no more information needed. why blow it up for no reason?

Comment: Hi Adomas, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: @pute because the answer is next to useless in case the link breaks. As we'd like answers to stay valuable beyond other websites going down, we deprecate link-only answers almost(?) automatically.

Comment: @Vincent i disagree. i know you also don't accept short answers (which outside SE are considered to be the best) - The question was: Whats that shadow called? Answer: Long Shadow. >> Question a 100% answered imho

Comment: Good point, and you are right in that short answers can be best! The A is still of value without it, indeed. Still--don't we all dislike clicking a dead link? :)

Comment: absolutely agree on the dead links. still this answer is valid and right and long enough